# arangodb AQL Limit > 1000

Tags: arangodb

I observe a problem when using `LIMIT > 1000` in AQL:

- the query is fast up to `LIMIT 1000`, lasting less then a second.
- starting from `LIMIT 1001`, the query becomes terribly slow... I abort it after 20 seconds.

Here are the examples:

```
FOR e IN subcategoryOf
LIMIT 1000
RETURN { "id": e._id, "text": e.text }
--> Fast, below a second
```

```
FOR e IN subcategoryOf
LIMIT 1, 1000
RETURN { "id": e._id, "text": e.text }
--> Fast, below a second
```

```
FOR e IN subcategoryOf
LIMIT 1, 1001
RETURN { "id": e._id, "text": e.text }
--> not answering after 20 seconds, manually aborted then.
```

Does anybody observe the same or have a hint for me?

I'm using ArangoDB 2.3.0 on Windows, and the aardvark AQL editor.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I just reproduced the issue locally. It does not look like a problem with the query itself. The third query runs fine & fast when initiated from the ArangoShell or via the ArangoDB REST APIs. However, when running it from the AQL Editor in the web interface, the UI seems to be missing the server's response for some reason. Will look into that.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks, this was a bug in the web interface. I have fixed it in this commit: 
https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/7656efd82fcbb31160d2ca4842f72190491101b8

Comment: For info: this is fixed in version 2.3.1.